# How to get the arc length for .net DrawArc method

Tags: math, drawing, trigonometry

I would like to know how to get the arc length for these two shapes that I have drawn on a bitmap. The curves were drawn using the following methods:

```
'Half Round:
Dim gfxpath As New GraphicsPath
gfxpath.AddArc(outRect, 180, 180)
gfxpath.AddArc(inRect, 180, 180)
gfxpath.CloseFigure()
gfx.FillPath(b, gfxpath)
gfx.DrawPath(p, gfxpath)

'Quarter Round:
Dim gfxpath As New GraphicsPath
gfx.DrawArc(p, outRect, 270, 90)
gfx.DrawArc(p, inRect, 270, 90)
```

I just need the arc length for the outer arc (the arc bounded by the outer rectangle). Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks more like a math problem than a programming problem. Have you done a web search on the circumference/perimeter of an ellipse? There is no simple closed-form expression for the circumference. How close of an approximation do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no closed formula for elliptic arc length. It is expressed through so-named "elliptic integrals"

You can calculate numerical solution for integration of arc length.

If your arcs are half and quarter of full ellipse (it is not clear from pictures), you can use some approximation, for example, [Ramanujan one](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/ellipse-perimeter.html)

```
p = Pi * (3*(a+b)+Sqrt((3a+b)*(a+3b)))
```

For the first picture

```
len = p / 2 = 1.5708 * (3*(36+18)+Sqrt((3*36+18)*(36+3*18)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the link!